How to read floors climbed?
How to read floors climbed using HealthConnect and GoogleFit? As I see, GoogleFit does not write any data into FloorsClimbedRecord.
I tried to use FloorsClimbedRecord to read climbed floors but unfortunately it always null because GoogleFit does not write any data
